# How to Create a Model for to complex Json Strucuture in django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Latest Django 3.0 and Database: Postgress and frontend Angular using for this 
This is my example Json can we able to create for this Complex Json

```
{
        'id'              : '1',
        'name'            : 'A Walk Amongst Friends - Canvas Print',
        'handle'          : 'a-walk-amongst-friends-canvas-print',
        'description'     : 'Officia amet eiusmod eu sunt tempor voluptate laboris velit nisi amet enim proident et. Consequat ',
        'categories'      : [
            'Canvas Print',
            'Nature'
        ],
        'tags'            : [
            'canvas-print',
            'nature'
        ],
        'featuredImageId' : 1,
        'images'          : [
            {
                'id'  : 0,
                'url' : 'assets/images/ecommerce/a-walk-amongst-friends.jpg',
                'type': 'image'
            },
            {
                'id'  : 1,
                'url' : 'assets/images/ecommerce/braies-lake.jpg',
                'type': 'image'
            },
            {
                'id'  : 2,
                'url' : 'assets/images/ecommerce/fall-glow.jpg',
                'type': 'image'
            },
                        ],
        'priceTaxExcl'    : 9.309,
        'priceTaxIncl'    : 10.24,
        'taxRate'         : 10,
        'comparedPrice'   : 19.90,
        'quantity'        : 3,
        'sku'             : 'A445BV',
        'width'           : '22',
        'height'          : '24',
        'depth'           : '15',
        'weight'          : '3',
        'extraShippingFee': 3.00,
        'active'          : true
    },
```

Please Help On this to create a list of string and json objects in the django 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want the models for this JSON? Or do you have the models and want the serializer class? Or do you want to know how to save this in the DB with models already defined?

Comment: Yes, please provide the models and serializers(if any).

Comment: @zaphod100.10 can you please provide both